# split long list of equations into 2 columns in a document

Tags: equations, two-column, multicol

Good day. I have this list of equations on a latex document. I intend to split it into two columns to economize space. Here is the code I used:

```
begin{multicol}{2}
\textit{Chemical Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{equation*}
I\xrightarrow{K_{d}}2fR^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
R^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Thermal Initiation Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
3M\xrightarrow{K_{iterm}}M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Propagation Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}
\end{multicol}
```

This is what I am expecting to get below after using the `\multicol` command.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882512/how-to-split-long-list-of-equations-into-2-columns-in-a-document

Answer (score 1):

You should never use two consecutive `equation` environments. Use `gather`, for this case.

I present two possibilities, but I'd prefer the second one because the three equations are not split across columns.

For better rendering I set the vertical spaces around the equations a bit smaller than usual and also with no flexibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\smallbullet}{^{\scriptscriptstyle\bullet}}

\begin{document}

In the order you specified the reactions.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\abovedisplayskip=0.67\abovedisplayskip
\belowdisplayskip=0.67\belowdisplayskip
\noindent\textit{Chemical Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{gather*}
I\xrightarrow{K_{d}}2fR\smallbullet
\\
R\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}\smallbullet
\end{gather*}

\noindent\textit{Thermal Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{gather*}
3M\xrightarrow{K_{\mathrm{iterm}}}M_{1}\smallbullet+M_{2}\smallbullet
\\
M_{1}\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}\smallbullet
\\
 M_{2}\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}\smallbullet
\end{gather*}

\noindent\textit{Chain Propagation Reaction:}
\begin{equation*}
P_{n}\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}\smallbullet
\end{equation*}
\end{multicols}

Modifying the order to get the reactions together.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\abovedisplayskip=0.67\abovedisplayskip
\belowdisplayskip=0.67\belowdisplayskip
\noindent\textit{Chemical Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{gather*}
I\xrightarrow{K_{d}}2fR\smallbullet
\\
R\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}\smallbullet
\end{gather*}

\noindent\textit{Chain Propagation Reaction:}
\begin{equation*}
P_{n}\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}\smallbullet
\end{equation*}

\noindent\textit{Thermal Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{gather*}
3M\xrightarrow{K_{\mathrm{iterm}}}M_{1}\smallbullet+M_{2}\smallbullet
\\
M_{1}\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}\smallbullet
\\
 M_{2}\smallbullet+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}\smallbullet
\end{gather*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@egreg and @user187802.Both approaches worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it works for me. Is this what you wanted?
Check this out: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns
Also use 'multicols' instead of 'multicol'

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First Section}
\blindtext

\section{Multi col section}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\textit{Chemical Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{equation*}
I \xrightarrow{K_{d}} 2fR^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
R^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Thermal Initiation Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
3M\xrightarrow{K_{iterm}}M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Propagation Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\end{multicols}
\section{Next Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also be done by a simple `array`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand\bull{\scriptscriptstyle{}^{\bullet}}
\begin{document}
    
    
\subsection*{Chemical Initiation Reaction:}
$\def\arraystretch{1.5}\begin{array}{@{}l>{\hspace{6em}}l}
    I \xrightarrow{K_{d}}2fR^{\bull} &
      M_{1}^{\bull}+M \xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}^{\bull} \\
    R^{\bull}+M \xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}^{\bull}&
      M_{2}^{\bull}+M  \xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}^{\bull}\\
 \rlap{\itshape Thermal Initiation Reaction:} & \rlap{\itshape Chain Propagation Reaction:}\\
    3M \xrightarrow{K_{iterm}}M_{1}^{\bull}+M_{2}^{\bull} &
      P_{n}^{\bull}+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}^{\bull}
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]